# War deployment failing on Jboss 7.4

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, undertow

I am migrating from Jboss 6.4 to Jboss 7.4, First I have not made any changes in war file and tried to deploy it on Jboss 7.4, but I was getting below error. This error is coming for all filter and servlet classes which are configured in web.xml file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010011: Filter log4jServletFilter of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter does not implement javax.servlet.Filter
at io.undertow.servlet.api.FilterInfo.<init>(FilterInfo.java:74)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:801)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:276)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
... 6 more
```

Then I tried with excluding undertow subsystem in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file as below. This time I was able to deploy war file without error, but application is not accessible with root context or any different way. On jboss admin console War is showing in active state but still accessible.

```
<exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="undertow" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
```

Could anyone advise me to resolve filter or servlet class error?

Comment: Do you have any Javaee API in your war ?

Comment: Yes, but all I kept them in custom module

Comment: You need to remove the Jakarta EE API JAR's, probably servlet in your case, from your WAR. Those are provided by the container and should not be there.

Comment: There was javax.servlet jar (<resource-root path="javax.servlet-4.0.1.jar"/>) in my custom module.xml so I commented it and issue is resolved. Thanks for your help. @James R. Perkins

Comment: Is this issue  resolved?